# Is there a solution to implement this scenario?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Suppose a user1 in a network wants to change data in a smart contract function, but before this transaction is pushed to the chain the other participants of the network receives a notification saying that user1 has made changes to the function and after the other participants verify this changes only then the transaction will be pushed to the chain.

Can someone help me with this. I'm a beginner in blockchain tech.

Comment: What do you mean "made changes to the function"?

Comment: i meant like the user entered some value into the function

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean to ask if there's any way to make it that a transaction is only mined if it's pre-approved? If not, can you help me understand the question a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

This option is possible when using, for example, the Hyper Ledger Fabric platform. This is not possible for Ethereum. But you can implement another mechanism - the data is initially stored in the preliminary storage of the contract, and after notification and receipt of the necessary confirmations, it is transferred to the main storage of the smart contract.

A simple version of the contract, where confirmation is specified by the minimum number of votes, is shown below:

1. User1 submits proposed changes using the **SubmitRequest** method. At the same time, a **VoteRequest** event is generated, notifying of the arrival of a request for voting.
2. Other users, having captured the event, receive the request data through the **GetRequest** method and confirm the request transactionally by calling the **AllowRequest** method.
3. When the last required confirmation is received (in the example, 5 of them are required), the processing of the confirmed request data is automatically started.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.8 <0.6.0;
    
    contract Confirmation
    {

      struct Request
      {
          bytes32  Attr1 ;
           int256  Attr2 ;
           int256  VotesCnt ;
         mapping (address => bytes32) Votes ;
      }

    mapping (bytes32 => Request) Requests ;

       event VoteRequest(bytes32) ;

       constructor() public
       {
       }
    
       function SubmitRequest(bytes32  id_, bytes32  attr1, int256  attr2) public payable
       {
            Requests[id_]=Request({     Attr1: attr1,
                                        Attr2: attr2,
                                     VotesCnt:    0  }) ;
                
           emit  VoteRequest(id_) ;
       }

       function GetRequest(bytes32  id_) public view returns (bytes32, int256 retVal) 
       {
           return(Requests[id_].Attr1, Requests[id_].Attr2) ;
       }

       function AllowRequest(bytes32  id_) public
       {
           if(Requests[id_].Votes[tx.origin]=="Y")  return ;
           
              Requests[id_].Votes[tx.origin]="Y" ;
              Requests[id_].VotesCnt++ ;
           
           if(Requests[id_].VotesCnt==5)  {

//          Process request data

                                          }
       }
    
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this solution mad jackal